# Inconsistent Behaviour of once()

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been testing my code on **Firebase Emulator**. My code is supposed to retrieve the most recent posts from my RT database while paginating the data:

```dart
Future<Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>?> fetchData({
  int? startAfter,
  int? endBefore,
  bool syncData = false,
}) async {
  Query query = _ref.child('posts').orderByChild('date');

  if (syncData) {
    await query.keepSynced(true);
  }

  if (startAfter != null) {
    query = query.startAfter(startAfter);
  }

  if (endBefore != null) {
    query = query.endBefore(endBefore);
  }

  query = query.limitToLast(15);

  final event = await query.once(DatabaseEventType.value);

  ...
}
```

Also, I have a listener attached to the same location:

```dart
void listenChanges(int startAfter) {
  final reference = _ref
      .child('posts')
      .orderByChild('date')
      .startAfter(startAfter)
      .limitToLast(1);

  reference.onChildAdded.listen((event) {
    ...
  });
}
```

The problem is the inconsistent behavior of [`once()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html). I know it's supposed to read the data from the local cache immediately, and only if the data is not available there, it will check on the server. However, I get different results every time. Sometimes, I'm able to receive the most recent data even though I do not enable `keepSynced`. Sometimes, I'm not even when I enable it.

Does `once()` retrieve the updated value if a listener is already attached to the same location? If so, the odd thing is that I call the listener after calling `once()`, but it still "sometimes" gets the updated value. Is that because the local cache expires after some time?

## Edit:

Here is my security rules on Firebase Emulator:

```json
"posts": {
  ".read": "auth != null && (query.limitToLast <= 15 || query.limitToFirst <= 15)",
  "$id": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Can query-based security rules be the reason behind the inconsistent behavior of `once()`?

Comment: Even though I know quite well how the database works in this scenario, I'm having a hard time understanding the problem here. It might be due to the amount of "sometimes", but it'd probably also help if you `print` the problematic data and show that in the question - as without that I have no idea what's going wrong. --- In general, if you think the problem is caused by the way `once()` and local persistence interact, consider using `get()`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/get.html

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but if you think the problem is caused by the way `once()` and local persistence interact, consider using the newer [`get()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/get.html). This method reverses the logic and (if there is a connection to the database) it first gets the value from the server, and only then calls your callback.

Comment: I need to make sure that my users will always get new posts, but also won't download the ones that were already downloaded before. However, `once()` seems to return no posts occasionally although there is a new post. Using `get()` all the time isn't ideal to me since there is no reason to read the same data from the server if it isn't updated. I think there should be a detailed explanation in the docs regarding how `once()` works. Right now, I cannot know when I should force the app to ignore the local cache and read the data from the server instead.

Comment: Here again "occasionally" is really hard to help with. Given that the code is stable, there must be some specific reason that you either get the updated data or not. If you can find that, we can probably help better.

Comment: Thank you. I can't find a specific reason because there is no apparent error or log, but I also think that it might somehow be related to Firebase Emulator. I know that some queries don't work well with the security rules specified on the Emulator. Do you think that would be the main cause of the inconsistency?

Comment: I added my security rules to the post.